# Spacemacs and IBus

Tags: spacemacs

I've just installed `spacemacs`. Of four IBus Input Methods `spacemacs` likes `English` and `Russian`. `Ancient Greek` and `Church Slavonic` is seen as `English`. Needless to say that outside `spacemacs` everything is OK. There is a lot of know how about Chinese and other East Asian languages, which is understandable. Unfortunately, exotic European languages command little attention.

How am I to go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: Arch Linux, emacs 25.3